# can't save @RelationshipEntity

Tags: java, nosql, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm try to save some @RelationshipEntity:
I've questionnaires, each of them related to some questions.
First I tried like follow:

```
@RelatedToVia
private Set<HasQuestionRelationship> question = new HashSet<HasQuestionRelationship();
```

and save just the root. That brings me to this problem:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124316-Spring-Data-Neo4j-NullPointerException-with-RelatedToVia and this open issue https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-216?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel#issue-tabs

then i tried to save just one relation:

```
@RelatedToVia(elementClass=HasQuestionRelationship.class, type="HAS_QUESTION", direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
private HasQuestionRelationship question2;
```

my relation class looks like:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="HAS_QUESTION")
public class HasQuestionRelationship {
    @GraphId
    Long id;

    private String name;

    @StartNode
    private QuestionnaireNode questionnaire;

    @EndNode
    private QuestionNode question;

    public HasQuestionRelationship() {
    }

    public HasQuestionRelationship(QuestionnaireNode questionnaireNode,
            QuestionNode question, String string) {
        if (question == null)
            System.out.println("csxa");
        this.questionnaire = questionnaireNode;
        this.question = question;
        this.name = string;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public QuestionnaireNode getQuestionnaire() {
        return questionnaire;
    }

    public void setQuestionnaire(QuestionnaireNode questionnaire) {
        this.questionnaire = questionnaire;
    }

    public QuestionNode getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(QuestionNode question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

}
```

my class questionnaire looks like this:

```
public class QuestionnaireNode extends BaseNode {
    @RelatedToVia(elementClass=HasQuestionRelationship.class, type="HAS_QUESTION", direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
    private HasQuestionRelationship question2;

    public QuestionnaireNode() {}

    public QuestionnaireNode(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }

    public QuestionnaireNode(String name, QuestionNode question) {
        setName(name);
        this.question2 = new HasQuestionRelationship(this, question, "testrelation");
    }

    public HasQuestionRelationship getQuestion2() {
        return question2;
    }

    public void setQuestion(HasQuestionRelationship question) {
        this.question2 = question;
    }
}
```

Now, I tried to save some testdata:

```
    QuestionNode question = new TextQuestionNode("question");
    QuestionnaireNode questionnaire = new QuestionnaireNode("questionnaire");
    HasQuestionRelationship relationtype = new HasQuestionRelationship(questionnaire, question, "mytest");
    questionnaire.setQuestion(relationtype);


    try {
        myRepository.save(question);
        myRepository.save(questionnaire);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

No exception is thrown. Im happy, but if i look into my database, i see just 2 nodes, but no relationship between them. Where is my fault?

Thanks

Comment: What version of SDN are you using? We added the handling of single @RelatedToVia fields only recently. Please either update to 2.1.M1 or use an Set<HasQuestionRelationship> as a workaround meanwhile. (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-182)

Comment: ah ok, i'll try this at after this weekand ^^, thanks for the answer